# Cambios de svg a png no se aplican

Tags: java, svg

Tenia un `.svg`, lo cambie y le puse un gradiente.

Después lo convertí a un `.png`, pero el gradiente no está en el nuevo `.png`.

He intentado convertir el `.svg` a `.png` con un convertidor de internet pero aún así el gradiente no se pasa.

Cuando abro el `.svg` con `Illustrator` no puedo ver el gradiente. En la previsualización del `.svg` puedo ver el gradiente.

Me da este error:

```
org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException El atributo 'd' del elemento <path> es invalido.
```

Mi pregunta es:

Si alguien se ha encontrado con este o otro error similar, o tiene alguna idea de como arreglarlo, podrías darme algún consejo sobre como arreglarlo?

Mi convertidor:

```
public void svgToPng() throws MalformedURLException {

String svg= "/Users/userName/svg/";
File folder = new File(svg);

for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {

    String[] codigoAux = fileEntry.getName().split("\\.");

    if (codigoAux[0].isEmpty()) {

        LOGGER.debug("Name of file is empty");

    } else {
        try {

            PNGTranscoder transcoder = new PNGTranscoder();

            String svgURI = fileEntry.toURI().toURL().toString();
            TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);

            String outputPath = "/Users/userName/png/";

            OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + codigoAux[0] + ".png");
            TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

            transcoder.transcode(input, output);

            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();


        }catch (TranscoderException ex) {

            LOGGER.error(ex);

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            LOGGER.error(ex);

        }

    }


}

}
```

Y aquí está mi elemento path:

```
<path fill="#D1E9FD" d="M7095.36-13.684c800.463,818.206,1299.013,1969.505,1299.013,3244.739             c0,633.732-123.293,1236.744-345.429,1783.602H305.852C83.733,4467.799-39.558,3864.79-39.558,3231.055             c0-1275.234,498.537-2426.534,1299.021-3244.739H7095.36z"></path>
```

Y mi elemento style:

```
<style>        #Countries path, #Countries polygon {        fill: url(#grad1);        filter: url(#dropshadow);        }    </style>
```

Y mi elemento linearGradient:

```
<linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">        
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:1"></stop>        
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#FFE69C;stop-opacity:1"></stop>    
</linearGradient>
```

El resultado esperado es un png con el gradiente.

Comment: El path tendría que tener como fill el gradiente. En el código tiene un azul claro como fill. Además sería interesante ver el gradiente.

Comment: No quiero que el path tenga el gradiente, el path debe tener ese azul claro. Añado donde tengo el gradiente y donde hago una referencia hacia el. Graciss per s'ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

El formato que tienes en tu SVG es incorrecto y por eso no lo puedes en (casi) ningún sitio. Prueba a hacerlo de nuevo, porque es muy probable que contenga errores.

Comment: Arreglarlos a mano no es una tarea trivial. Lo recomendable es que lo hagas de nuevo, dudo que te cueste más trabajo que intentar una implementación de un posible convertidor usando Java.